I have implemented SSL for odbc server in Marklogic but it's showing error_invalid_http_response
I have implemented ssl for Marklogic ODBC server. I followed the Marklogic documentation steps.
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security-guide/en/configuring-ssl-on-app-servers.html
After successfully importing the signed certificate it is expired. Also, when I try to access ssl through the browser it's showing error_invalid_http_response.
Do we need to restart the cluster to resolve this issue?

There are some client configurations you need to make, in order to connect ODBC via SSL. As indicated in the MarkLogic documentation (quoted below), refer to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/libpq-ssl.html#LIBPQ-SSL-CLIENTCERT for the client configurations.
Enabling Client Certificate Verification on an ODBC App Server

To enable client certificate verification for a MarkLogic ODBC App Server, you need a valid certificate/private key combination. Confirm that the ODBC App Server has a certificate template selected in the ssl certificate template field, has the appropriate certificate client authority selected in the ssl client certificate authorities field, and that ssl require client certificate is set to true.
To configure PostgreSQL for client certificate verification, point to the path of the certificate with the environment variable PGSSLCERT and the path of the private key with PGSSLKEY, as described in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/libpq-ssl.html#LIBPQ-SSL-CLIENTCERT.
For details on how to enable SSL for App Servers, see Configuring SSL on App Servers in the Security Guide.

